# How to use template parameter class on virtual methods?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, c++11

I know that is not possible to use template on virtual method, because the compile there is no way to know how to implement all possibilities, but what I need is to use template on a restricted way, like that:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
class MatBase {
 public:
  static constexpr size_t order = N;

  using value_type = T;

  MatBase() = default;
  virtual ~MatBase() = default;

  template<class Fn = T(T)>
  virtual void Map(Fn&& fn) = 0;

  template<class Fn = T(T,T)>
  virtual T Reduce(Fn&& fn) = 0;
};
```

It means, Fn uses the template declared on class, so I think it is possible to compiler infer all possible types. Are there way to do something like that C++?

Comment: Why can't you just write `virtual void Map(T(&&)(T)) = 0;`?

Comment: What is the difference between T(&&)(T) and T(*)(T)?

Comment: One is an rvalue reference and one is a pointer. TBH I prefer @James's version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you stated you cannot have a templated virtual function. However, why do you need templates at all? See the following example code.

#### Example Code

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, size_t N>
class MatBase
{
public:
    static constexpr size_t order = N;

    using MapFn = T (*)(T);

    using ReduceFn = T (*)(T, T);

    using value_type = T;

    MatBase() = default;
    virtual ~MatBase() = default;

    virtual void Map(MapFn&& fn) {}

    virtual T Reduce(ReduceFn&& fn) {}
};

int main()
{
    MatBase<int, 3> m;
    return 0;
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/bwFh3m)

---

A more flexible solution may consider using `std::function` (e.g., `std::function<T (T)>`) for the parameters since it gives the caller more flexibility. For example, the caller could use a normal function, a member function, a lambda expression, or a functor object.

Comment: Would be better use `using MapFn = T (&&)(T);` and just call virtual void `Map(MapFn fn) = 0;`?

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure why you were using `&&` so I just kept them. If you're using normal function pointers then I'd probably use `virtual void Map(MapFn fn) = 0;`.

Comment: @Alex Note, you may want to accept `std::function<T (T)>` as the parameter type since it's much more flexible (i.e., the caller can use a normal function, lambda expression, member function).

Comment: In fact this function will be passed to CUDA, so I have a problem to use std::function, I need to pass as a template parameter by copy or move.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer will work with plain, garden variety, function pointers. But using a little bit of type-erasure, or some adaptation of it, should also be possible to make this work with instances of classes that implement a suitable `operator()` member.

I'll write this out for `Map()`. Repeating the same approach for `Reduce()` is similar, and will be a homework assignment:

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, size_t N>
class MatBase
{
public:
    static constexpr size_t order = N;

    using value_type = T;

    MatBase() = default;
    virtual ~MatBase() = default;

    template<typename Arg> void Map(Arg && arg)
    {
        std::function< value_type(value_type> > f=
               [&]
               (value_type value)
               {
                   return arg(value);
               };

        do_map(f);
     }

     virtual void do_map(std::function< value_type(value_type) > &)=0;
};
```